# How to create feature captcha in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to feature captcha the same as Binance. However, I don't know where to start Or lib support for this feature?

1. How to automation cut 1 part of picture
2. How to move this part follow slide captcha

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z36I3.png)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use this package for my project [slider_captcha](https://pub.dev/packages/slider_captcha)

Comment: Thank you. Silder captcha is my package. It is result  after a few month research.

Comment: :v ngầu đó bác @TrầnVănHiếu